# Adding a new instance of an object to each object in an array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an array of movie clips `highlights[i]` and I want to add a rectangle hit area sprite to each object. How do I do this without causing naming conflicts?

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < highLights.length; i++)
                {
                    this[i + 'Zone'] = new HitZone(highLights[i].x, highLights[i].y, highLights[i].width, highLights[i].height));
                    highLights[i].addChild(this[i + 'Zone']);
                    addChild(highLights[i]);
                }
```

Comment: What naming conflict are you running into?

Comment: I would recommend doing this with an array rather than using the dynamic nature of a MovieClip.

Answer (score 0):

To set Sprites or MovieClips hitArea you need to assign designated sprite to it's hitArea property like [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728245/as3-defining-hit-area).

eg. `hilights[i].hitArea = this[i +"Zone"];`

you should not name the variable starting with a number, `i`. [Name guidelines here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000478.html)

also are you using elsewhere this dynamic property? if not than use local variable like so:

```
var _oHitZone:HitZone;
var _oHilight:MovieClip;//assume that it is MovieClip
for (var i:int = 0; i < highLights.length; i++)
{
    _oHilight = hilights[i];
    _oHitZone = new HitZone(_oHilight.x, _oHilight.y, _oHilight.width, _oHilight.height));
    _oHilight.addChild(_oHitZone);
    _oHilight.hitArea = _oHitZone;
    addChild(_oHilight);
}
```

this should help

Answer (score -1):

Use array for storing HitZones.

```
var zones:Array = [];
var zone:HitZone;
for (var i:int = 0; i < highLights.length; i++)
            {
                zone = new HitZone(highLights[i].x, highLights[i].y, highLights[i].width, highLights[i].height));
                zones.push(zone); 
                highLights[i].addChild(zone);
                addChild(highLights[i]);
            }
```

If you don't need store zones than don't create array.

Answer (score -1):

```
var hitZone:HitZone;
for (var i:int = 0; i < highLights.length; i++)
{
  hitZone = new HitZone(highLights[i].x, highLights[i].y, highLights[i].width, highLights[i].height));
  highLightsthis[i + 'Zone'] = hitZone;
  addChild(hitZone );
}
```